# Google visualization line chart not showing annotations (no error in javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using the following code and while the chart loads fine, the annotations don't appear and furthermore there is no error returned.

Here is the same example in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MooseEagleShark/2sdxv5r9/).  Beating my brains out over here.  Thank you in advance if you can see what I cannot.

What gives?

```
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'GIP'); // Implicit domain label col.
    data.addColumn('number', 'Production Curve Percentage'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}); // annotation role col.

    data.addRows([

        [2.7334,0.94, 'note 1-1', ],
            [1.7899,0.653, 'note 2-2', ],
            [1.444,0.94, 'note 3-3', ],
            [1.7704,0.789, 'note 4', ],
            [1.7773,1.083, 'note 5', ],
            [2.7703,1.308, 'note 6', ],
            [1.7173,1.026, 'note 7', ],
    ]);

        var options = {
             title: 'GIP2 vs. performance',
            annotations: {
                textStyle: {
                  fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  bold: true,
                  italic: true,
                  color: '#871b47',     // The color of the text.
                  auraColor: '#d799ae', // The color of the text outline.
                  opacity: 0.8          // The transparency of the text.
                }
              },
            pointShape: 'circle',
            pointSize: '4',
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Performance', 
                },
            hAxis: {
                title: "GIP", 
                //logScale: 'true',
                //format:  "####",
            },
            seriesType: "line",
            trendlines: {
              0: {
                type: 'linear',
                visibleInLegend: true,
                visibleInLegend: true,
                showR2: true,
              }
            }

        }


        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_GIPvsPCP'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
```

Comment: First things first, AVOID extraneous commas! They will cause all sorts of problems in IE. Better browsers like Chrome or FF may eat them right up and still work, but IE will not. Make sure you don't have commas after the last elements in an array, or right before a closing parenthesis. Second, your annotations list is empty. You aren't telling it how to display the annotations

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I originally had an annotations list specified, but apparently it is not necessary and the annotations don't display whether or not I specify the annotations list, so I guess I'm still SOL ( i did edit the example though so other people wont suggest the same thing).  Any commas in particular?  Did you get it to work on the jsfiddle?  Thank you.

Comment: As I said, get rid of the commas after the last elements in an array (in data.addRows(), for example), and also if it is the last attribute in an object block. For example, look at where you set vAxis. After 'Performance' you have a comma, but then close the block. You should only use a comma to separate attributes. If you aren't planning to put another one after it, you shouldn't have a comma. Same goes for the last element in "trendlines" within the "0" block. `showR2:true` should not have a comma after it because you don't add any attributes after that one

Comment: Everything I'm reading says that annotation box styling is available, but I can't find any examples where someone uses a scatter chart with annotations. It may just be unsupported at the moment. I'd recommend trying to submit something to: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/ and see if they can't help out, or add some sort of support for the issue

Comment: Thanks Samuel Cook.  That was exactly it.  Only Linecharts support annotations (not scatterchart) and if you set the line width to 0 then you get the same effect...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Scattercharts don't support annotations yet.  The easy workaround is to change:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_GIPvsPCP'));
```

to

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_GIPvsPCP'));
```

and then specify:

```
lineWidth: 0,
```

to get the same effect.

Thanks Samuel Cook.  Official response from Google here: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Modified%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=1817